# Heroku file uploading and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku

I tried upload file to Heroku using https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload, on my PC it works great, but on Heroku there are this error:

```
{"errno":-2,"code":"ENOENT","syscall":"open","path":"./public/owner_photo/f28397baea8fb4d6f6dafed9f5586a9ac0b46843acf1120a0ecad24755cfff57.jpeg"}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: There is probably not a folder called `./public/owner_photo` on your Heroku instance

Comment: My guess is that you don't have permission to save files on disk with heroku

Answer (score 2):

Heroku has an immutable file system, meaning you can't make changes to, or additions to the file system. You'll need to store your uploads somewhere else, like Amazon S3.

Also, many upload packages by default store the uploaded file in a temp directory. So even if you are sending them to S3, you'll still need to make sure the methods you use don't attempt to do that, or set an option to disable it. I'm not familiar with `express-fileupload` so I can't say what methods do or do not attempt to store copies on the filesystem.

I have successfully implemented this using `multiparty` so I could be of more specific help with that package.

Comment: could you please explain how you did this?  I am struggling to find a solution